# How can I select an element based on the class of another element somewhere else on the page

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I know I can select the descendant or sibling of a specific class with combinators. I have a situation where I want to style an element on any page where a totally separate element contains a certain class. This is for a wordpress site where some pages have a particular category, which adds that category's name to an element on the page. I want to style a totally separate element on any of those pages, but the element is not a descendant or sibling of the one with the class I'm looking for.

Imagine this simplified scenario:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div class="desired-cat"></div>
    </div>
<div>
<div>
    <div>
        <div class="target-element"></div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Is it possible for me to style .target-element on any page where .desired-cat is used somewhere on that page? Thanks!

Comment: Using pure CSS? No. Using jQuery? Maybe. No selector currently exists that can select a previous or parent element in pure CSS. Here's a list of all selectors currently available : https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors

Comment: You should add the category as a class to the detail page server side. That way it's easy to do custom category styling.

Comment: I don't think this is in the realm of CSS possibilities, it can't traverse the DOM tree "upwards" (to parents). You can achieve this quite simply with JavaScript though, using ```document.querySelector``` or ```document.getElementsByClassName``` to find your nodes and then use ```.classList.add("some-class")``` to style the target-element.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate of another question where I've written a bit of an encyclopedic answer - but the long and short of it is that there isn't a selector that checks for the presence of some other element anywhere within the page regardless of its location.

Answer (score 0):

you can use HTML Dom getlElementByClassName() method to select all elements in the HTML file.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
  x[0].innerHTML = "Hello World!";
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div class="example">First div element with class="example".</div>

<div class="example">Second div element with class="example".</div>



<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can also manipulate class itself

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress you can use [body classes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/).

Where each page, category, tag, etc., has its own class.

So you can use these classes to style specific areas.

Example:

```html
...
<body class="archive category category-physiotherapy category-76 logged-in admin-bar wp-custom-logo hfeed customize-support">
...
```